# Variables copied incorrectly from a Fortran to a cuda c program

Tags: c++, cuda, fortran, gpu

I have been trying to write a program that uses GPU to compute an integral using gaussian quadrature numerical integration. I have been trying to figure out why this program is not working. I think I pinned it down to the fact that the parameters that are passed in the function call d_one are not being copied correctly to the cuda c code. I am not sure why this is happening. I spent so much time trying to figure it out, but I could not get anywhere with it.

Here are the two programs:

The Fortran Program:

```
    implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
    parameter ( nlinx = 22) ! Total number of mesh regions
    dimension sx(3*nlinx),swx(3*nlinx)

    xa = 0.d0
    xb = 5.d0
    ! In the following "nptx" is the total number of integration
    ! points. So, it is (nlinx * 3)
    call meshwt1(xa,xb,nlinx,ntan,sx,swx,nptx)

    ans0 = 0.d0

    CAll d_one(sx, swx, nptx, ans0)

    print *, ans0

    stop

    end

SUBROUTINE MESHWT1(A,B,N,NT,X,W,NTOT)
  implicit real*8(a-h,o-z)
  !3*N LINEAR POINTS FOR A TO B
  !NT=0 OR 1, 3*NT TAN PTS FOR B TO INFINITY
  !NTOT= 3*(N+NT)
  DIMENSION X(*),W(*),G(3),GW(3)
  G(1)  = -0.7745966
  G(2)  =  0.0000000
  G(3)  = -G(1)
  GW(2) = 0.8888888
  GW(1) = 0.5555555
  GW(3) = GW(1)
  Y = N
  DX = ( B - A ) / Y
  K = 0
  XA = A - DX
  XB = A
  DO 2 I = 1, N
  XA = XA + DX
  XB = XB + DX
  DO 2 J = 1, 3
  K = K + 1
  X(K) = 0.5 * ( XA + XB ) + 0.5 * ( XB - XA ) * G(J)
2 W(K) = 0.5 * ( XB - XA ) * GW(J)
  NTOT = K
  IF( NT .EQ. 1 )  GO TO 3
  GO TO 5
3 NTOT = K + 3
  DO 4 J = 1, 3
  K = K + 1
  Y = ( 1.0 + G(J) ) * 3.14159 * 0.25
  X(K) = XB + DTAN(Y)
4 W(K) = GW(J) * 3.14159 * 0.25 / ( DCOS(Y) ) ** 2
5 CONTINUE
  RETURN
  END
```

The CUDA Program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
__global__ void loop_d(float *a, float *b, int N, float *ans)
{
    __shared__ float temp[66];
    int idx = threadIdx.x;
    if (idx < 66)
    {
              temp[idx] = a[idx] * b[idx];
    }
    __syncthreads();
    if (0 == idx)
    {
            float sum = 0.0;
            for (int i=0; i < 66; i++)
            {
                    sum += temp[i];
            }
            *ans = sum;
    }
}
// The following function is called from the Fortran program
extern "C" void d_one_(float *a, float *b, int *Np, float *ans)
{
    float *a_d, *b_d, *ans_d; // Declaring GPU Copies of the parameters passed
    int blocks = 1; // Number of blocks used
    int N = *Np;  // Number of threads is determined by the parameter nptx passed from the Fortran program

    // Allocating GPU memory
    cudaMalloc( (void **)&a_d, sizeof(float) * N);
    cudaMalloc( (void **)&b_d, sizeof(float) * N);
    cudaMalloc( (void **)&ans_d, sizeof(float) );
    // Copying information from CPU to GPU
    cudaMemcpy( a_d, a, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( b_d, b, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( ans_d, ans, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    // Calling the function on the GPU
    loop_d<<< blocks, N >>>(a_d, b_d, N, ans_d);
    cudaMemcpy( a, a_d, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    cudaMemcpy( b, b_d, sizeof(float) * N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );
    cudaMemcpy( ans, ans_d, sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost );

    // Freeing GPU memory
    cudaFree(a_d);
    cudaFree(b_d);
    cudaFree(ans_d);
    return;
}
```

The output of the program should be 12.49999. I am getting an answer on the order of -314. Thank you for any input you provide!

Comment: Anyone using implicit typing in the 21st century deserves all the pain that comes barreling down the turnpike towards them.  It's probably not the source of the errors you report, but it's a matter of seconds to modify the program to eliminate the possibility that it is the source of the errors.

Comment: completely agree with HPM. the reason I love FORTRAN is because any code should start with `IMPLICIT NONE`. Imho the best motto ever for coding in general.

Comment: At least he is using an explicit `implicit` statement that makes it dead obvious that he is trying to pass `real*8` variables into `float`s.

Comment: Probably worth writing an answer about that.

Comment: I miss error checking. And did you debug your code? Are the values in host memory correct? And why do you copy `a_d` and `b_d` back to host? Why do you copy `ans` to device memory? (And I hope that this code is just a minimal example because the kernel is really bad.)

Comment: @Shadow I am still new to GPU programming. I just started about a week ago. I would like any suggestions you have regarding improving the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decide on whether you want to use single-precision or double precision floating point variables.

At the moment, you are using double precision `real*8`on the Fortran side and single precision `float` on the C(++) side.

Use either `real*4` and `float` together, or `real*8` and `double`.

Comment: Thank you very much! This did solve my problem! I appreciate your help so much!